# MongoDB scheme collection for monitoring sensors

Tags: mongodb

I'm designing a monitoring application and hesitating about mongodb scheme. The app will monitoring 32 sensors. Each sensors will have multiple scalar value, but that not the same between sensors (could be differents units, config etc..). Scalar data will be pushed every minute. And for each sensors, there will be one or some array (3200 value) to be pushed too. Each sensors could have a completly different config, that have to be stored too (config is complex, but does not change often at all) and of course event log.
I don't know if i have to create different collection for each sensors, with a flat db like :

- Config
- 1D_data
- 2D_data
- event_log

Or creating sub collection for each sensors with config/1d/2d in each of them.

Request to display data will be "display all 1D from one sensor" (to display a trend over time) and "show a 2D_data at this time".

If it was only scalar value i'll chose the first solution, but dunno if 2D "big" results is also on the game.
Thanks for your advices !

Answer (score 0):

It seems a little oversimplified at first but all the information can be stored in a *single* collection.  There is no added value in having 32 different collections.  Each document will have a shape similar to this:

```js
    {
      "device":"D1",
      "created": ISODate("2017-10-02T13:59:48.194Z"),
      "moreCommonMetadata": { whatever: 77 },
      "data": {
        "color":"red",
        "maxAmps":10,
        "maxVolts":240
      }
    },
  {
      "device":"D2",
      "created": ISODate("2017-10-02T13:59:48.194Z"),
      "moreCommonMetadata": { whatever: 77 },
      "data": {
        "bigArray":[23,34,45,56,7,78,78,78],
        "adj": [{foo:'bar', bin:'baz'}, {corn:'dog'}],
        "vers": 2
      }
    }
```

Queries can easily sweep across the metadata, and the `data` field can be any shape and will be logically tied to the `device` field i.e. some value of the `device` field will drive logic to manipulate the `data` field.

A fairly comprehensive example can be found at
http://moschetti.org/rants/lhs.html

Comment: I doubt that we can access your local host

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit  Thanks for catching that; repaired.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Thanks ! Indeed it's more convenient for queries :)